# MQTT SSL-encryption on port 8883 using mosquitto.h and test.mosquitto.org

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am currently using a raspberry Pi as an MQTT publisher client, and decided to use the mosquitto.h library (https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html) to accomplish this. I have been able to publish messages on port 1883, however am unable to do the same with port 8883, and was wondering if anyone could help. I am using the test.mosquitto.org  broker for this.

In the linux terminal (with mosquitto-clients installed), using the command:

`mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t test/topic -m "test" -p 8883 --cafile /home/pi/Downloads/mosquitto.crt`
works just fine (where /home/pi/Downloads/mosquitto.crt is the path to the file containing the PEM encoded trusted CA certificate). However, using the mosquitto.h library:

```
    struct mosquitto *mosq;
    //initialise mosquitto library
    mosquitto_lib_init();
    //settup mosquitto instance
    mosq = mosquitto_new("Publisher", true, NULL);
    //settup SSL stuff
    int SSL = mosquitto_tls_set(mosq,"/home/pi/Prototype2/mosquitto.crt",NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    //connect to mqtt broker
    rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, "test.mosquitto.org", 8883, 60);
    //publish to mosquitto broker
    mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "test/topic",5, test, 0, false);
```

produces no errors, but doesn't do anything, so was wondering if someone could help? If not I can always use the `system()` command in c to input the commands directly into the Linux terminal, but would prefer to use the mosquitto.h library.

Any help would be much appreciated, if you need any more information don't hesitate to ask, thanks in advance.

*EDIT*
I will include an example someone can compile below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>  //for MQTT communication

int main ()
{
    // mosquitto publish setup
        int rc;
        struct mosquitto *mosq;

    //initialise mosquitto library
        mosquitto_lib_init();
        mosq = mosquitto_new("Publisher", true, NULL);
    int SSL = mosquitto_tls_set(mosq,"/home/pi/Prototype2/mosquitto.crt",NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL);
    //setup connection to broker at this IP address, port 8883, with 60 second timeout
        rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, "test.mosquitto.org", 8883, 60);
    //if connection is not successful, print error message and abort program
        if (rc != 0)
        {
                printf("Error, could not connect to broker, Error code : %d\n", rc);
                mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
                return -1;
        }

    //print success message
        printf("Connected to Broker\n");

    //publish  under topic test/topic
        int pub_1=mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "test/topic",5, "test", 0, false);

    
    printf("SSH flag=%d \nconnection flag =%d \npublish flag =%d\n",SSL, rc, pub_1);

    //disconnect from broker and destroy struct
        mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);
        mosquitto_destroy(mosq);

    //cleanup and free mallocs
        mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The file mosquitto.crt contains:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: "produces no errors" - so both `SSL` and `rc` are `MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS ` (`0`) as is the return code from `mosquitto_publish`?

Comment: Yes SSL and rc produces return code 0. However I haven't checked the return code for the mosquito_publish, I'll try that next, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If that does not help please modify your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. something someone else can compile to replicate your issue).

Comment: `mosquitto_publish` queues the message; you will need a [network loop](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#Network_loop(managed_by_libmosquitto)) to handle the transmission/acknowledgement. See [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/examples/publish) and [this answer from the author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097917/11810946).

Comment: @Brits apologies forgot to update you with this works great now! Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments calling `mosquitto_publish` just queues the message; the transmission and acknowledgment process is handled by a [network loop](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#Network_loop(managed_by_libmosquitto)) (which you need to initiate). The simplest way to run a message loop is probably:

```
/* Run the network loop in a background thread, this call returns quickly. */
rc = mosquitto_loop_start(mosq);
if(rc != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS){
    mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", mosquitto_strerror(rc));
    return 1;
}
```

That code is taken from [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/examples/publish); see [this answer from the author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097917/11810946) for further info.